# How to create custom space block below catalog.topnav ( Menu )

Tags: magento2.3.4, topmenu

I want to add **add-to-cart** and **Wishlist** under catalog.topnav ( Menu ) how to add right below menu bar.

[image]

Comment: do you want to move minicart in navigation ?

Comment: yes, i need to move minicart below menu bar, i mean create custom space and move minicart into this space.

Comment: FYI i have created custom theme inherit from blank theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move `minicart` to `catalog.topnav` use :

```
<move element="minicart" destination="catalog.topnav"/>
```

at

> app/design/frontend/{Packgae}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

[image]

**Update I:**

If you want minicart below nav you need to create a custom container and need to move it, like:

```
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <container name="test" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-class" after="navigation.sections"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="minicart" destination="test"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, i did same, but i need to move minicart into below menu bar https://snipboard.io/rq4K6i.jpg

Comment: I hope my point clear.

Comment: Yes, in that case we need to create a custom container!

Comment: please see my updates in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, its working. I just move my logo to catalog.topnav, its ok in web view but mobile view menu not wokring like three line left corner missing, Any help thanks.

Comment: welcome @zus,  for mobile view ,you need some additional CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117727/discussion-between-zus-and-pawan).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117727/discussion-between-zus-and-pawan

Comment: Other pages breadcrumb above the custom block, how to handle this situation?

Comment: Hi pawan, other pages, breadcrumbs section top custom space below, screenshot : https://snipboard.io/fi7C1G.jpg any help thanks.

Comment: any help appreciate, thanks.

Comment: I checked and minicart is above breadcrumbs on other pages too.

Comment: Did you see my screen shot?

Comment: Yes and tried on search page and it is showing correct..

Comment: finally done, <container name="test" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-class" before="breadcrumbs"/>

Comment: Hi pawan, i am added hero banner as a widget, here the issue is my custom div come below the hero banner, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @zus, You can use `after` & `before` for adjust block position.

Comment: How to apply after & before for widget block block-static-block

Comment: not for widget, you need to apply on custom block you moved!

Comment: Now my widget above my custom block, how to move my custom block above widget.